# RAID 6, SSD Cache, Journaling, mdadm, LVM, Filesystem Strategies for Data Resiliance

Tags: linux, raid, configuration, lvm, mdadm

I'm replacing a NAS server thats been in loyal service for almost a decade now. It will be repurposed as my offsite backup, but now I'm setting up a new NAS from scratch for homelab and need some pointers on how to implement the following priorities (in order of importance):

1. Data resilience

   - low chance of corruption
   - "set it and forget it"
2. Storage Space
3. Performance

With these hardware specs:

- Dedicated basic SSD for Ubuntu OS
- Dedicated ~7gb/s gaming SSD (2TB capacity) for caching and/or journaling
- 5x12TB SATA hdds
- 32-64GB ram (not sure what mobo supports yet, but at least 32gb DDR5)
- Adding a UPS for this machine to allow for graceful shutdown in times of power outage.

With specific technology questions including:

- RAID 6 or 2 mirrors striped (10?) with hot/cold swap
- mdadm caching, write only? read/write? what size/timing?
- Filesystem on top of RAID

  - lvm + ext4? (lots of experience)
  - lvm + btrfs? (very little experience)
  - just btrfs directly on RAID (zero experience)
  - ZFS (zero experience)
- Dedicated journaling partition (I think just for ext4? Maybe btrfs and zfs too?) on the fast SSD?

Some other notes about use:

- Mostly just syncthing 24/7 for dozens of tablets/phones and a couple laptops and desktops, so many frequent small writes all day long
- might throw a media server of some kind on there, so streaming over LAN but prob just to one device at a time.
- Maybe some live video recording from security cameras, but nothing intense.
- A couple long lived NFS mounts to the desktops
- Maybe a database service or two at some point either directly on this machine or with this machine serving as a secondary receive-only mirror.

On my old NAS, I used [a script](https://github.com/brianclements/iserb) for LVM live snapshoting and rsync to backup using hardlinks to a separate drive for basic user files. I might use this strategy again to backup to the offsite NAS unless there is something a different filesystem offers that's better.

Comment: lvm snapshots from underneath a live file system?  I [question the reliability of that backup strategy](https://serverfault.com/questions/23965/lvm-snapshots-as-a-backup-strategy).

Comment: @AndrewHenle LVM snapshots is not a viable backup strategy per se, but it's a correct first step. O.P. mentions rsync from snapshot afterwards; that's the correct second step. So your doubt makes no sense. However, I'd question the rsync as a valid backup strategy; there must be *a history* of backups, not just a single "latest" copy of a live data set, which is the only thing that rsync alone is able to achieve. In particular backup is often considered a ransomware insurance, and rsynced copy does not provide this reliably.

Comment: BTRFS or ZFS snapshots is more preferred way to make consistent backups than LVM+traditional file system. It skips the (required otherwise) step of fixing the filesystem in a snapshot. Also, ZFS provides send-receive interface which is even more efficient than rsync (because it doesn't compare files or parts to determine what to transfer, rather it takes changelog directly from the file system). Consider that serously.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov  I'd be afraid of incidents such as using lvm snapshots and capturing a database operation in the middle of an update and then using rsync to send that half-a-transaction to the backup system.  BTRFS or ZFS snapshots are at least guaranteed to be a consistent file system. And they're a LOT more efficient than rsync since differences are known and don't have to be discovered.  rsync has serious scalability problems.

Comment: Database backups should not have nothing to do with LVM snapshots. Databases provide their own techniques for backup, which must be used instead. However, the particular situation you mention is not a problem. If you catch a (properly designed) database mid-transaction in a LVM snapshot, after recovery it will behave as if that transaction did not existed, which is perfectly correct.

Comment: To clarify, the script I mentioned in the post does make use of hardlinks and symlinks to create an abstract filesystem level "history". One can browse by year/month/date/time in folders. It seemed less daunting at the time for me to be able to nfs mount the destination drive and just navigate folders on my filesystem then to worry about mounting snapshots on my server or use some other single purpose tool for that. But this strategy is best limited for basic user files. Services and databases (and they will come later) will probably be in data containers and have their own backup processes.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov can you elaborate on what you mean by fixing the filesystem in the snapshot? Are your saying that when the errors are filesystem level (maybe due to the RAID) that the snapshots will capture those as well? The ZFS changelog strategy seems very very enticing overall...

Comment: When you make a snapshot of a volume that contains a mounted and busy file system, the snapshot will capture it in a transient "dirty" state, like you pulled the power off that moment. And, just like after pulling the power you need to check consistency, you'll need to do that with the filesystem image in a snapshot. Journaling file system like ext4 should not be corrupted too much and I'd expect it will fix itself during mount, but *for backup purposes* I'd make sure it is clean and the data is valid before taking something from there. Use of ZFS snapshots completely avoids this hazard.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. How does btrfs stack up in that regard compared to zfs? And for simple examples using ext4, would forcing a ```fsck -pvcf``` of the snapshot before rsync be that extra security?

Comment: I am not sure. If you have mounted `ext4` with only *metadata* being journaled (as by default), your file system structure will be consistent after such cloning, but data won't, and therefore backup of the snapshot could contain damaged data. So you need to actually check *data consistency*, not just file system consistency. I can't evaluate all the possible problems in this design. As I said, ZFS avoids it all. BTRFS features are theoretically on par in this regard; I don't have so much experience with it. If I were to make choice, I'd choose ZFS for a production system.